PRESTASHOP Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Tools::jsonDecode() and array_push(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, string given in
I don't have a problem, I'm just droping my solution because someone may encounter this problem in the future.
When I tried to pre order something this problem appears:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Tools::jsonDecode() in C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\modules\preorderandnotification\preorderandnotification.php:1151 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\classes\Hook.php(1043): PreOrderAndNotification->hookActionValidateOrder(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\classes\Hook.php(418): HookCore::coreCallHook(Object(PreOrderAndNotification), 'hookActionValid...', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\classes\Hook.php(981): HookCore::callHookOn(Object(PreOrderAndNotification), 'actionValidateO...', Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\classes\PaymentModule.php(558): HookCore::exec('actionValidateO...', Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\modules\ps_wirepayment\controllers\front\validation.php(63): PaymentModuleCore->validateOrder(9, 10, 280.0, 'Pagos por trans...', NULL, Array, 1, false, 'f4ca56f1c06cb90...') #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\classes\controller\Controller.php(308): Ps_WirepaymentValidationModuleFrontController->postProcess() #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\classes\Dispatcher.php(510): ControllerCore->run() #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\index.php(28): DispatcherCore->dispatch() #8 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\modules\preorderandnotification\preorderandnotification.php on line 1151
And then the next problem (sorry I don't have the full text):
C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\modules\preorderandnotification\preorderandnotification.php:1153
I solved this by changing "Tools::jsonDecode()" for json_decode(), and then solved the next problem:
And solved this by changing:
`“$orders = isset($orders) && $orders ? json_encode($orders) : '';”`

for
   $orders = isset($orders) && $orders ? json_decode($orders, true) : [];
                        $orders[] = $order->id;
                        $orders_json = json_encode($orders);



Tools::jsonDecode() was marked as deprecated in November 2016 when version 1.7.0 was released. The fact that it is still in use in modules designed for PrestaShop 1.7+ is just bad practice on the part of module authors.
